# Dark matter and un-smoothness in spacetime

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, dark-matter

Since dark matter currently is only observable with its gravitational effects and nothing else can we theorize that dark matter is only non-smoothness in spacetime that has been there from the Big Bang. You might ask why would there be any non-smoothness from Big Bang?and in answer we could propose that if the current universe that we are in is the result of the explosion of a black hole which contained the matter and the energy in this world.this would also confirm the decrease of the dark matter’s effects as the universe ages. Because the universe is expanding the heterogeneity (the in-smoothness) is decreasing because it is scattering all over the spadetime.
Please address the bugs in the core idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/)

Comment: The 'non-smoothness' in space-time is what is basically observed with the CMB anisotropies. It has little to do with the very nature of dark matter.